# Func and lambda question

Tags: c#, .net

I have a declaration of

```
void Test (Func<bool> f)
```

I have a method like `bool getItem(string id)`

I can call like `Test ( ()=>getItem("123"))`, why?

I suppose that I can check I need 1 string parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Func<bool>` expects a function that returns a `bool`. `Func<T1>` has one output argument, then `Func<T1, T2>` takes a function with input T1 and output T2.  Each successive version allows an additional input argument, with the final generic type being the type of your output argument.

ex.: `Func<string, string, bool>` would be able to invoke `bool DoStuff(string s1, string s2)`

Quick Edit to clarify:  Test( () => getItem("123")) works because the start of your lambda declaration exposes no input arguments, and getItem returns a boolean.

Answer (score 4):

because the signature of Test requires the argument be a method that takes no parameters and returns a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Your method Test is defined as taking a parameter of `Func<bool>` which expects a method signature similar to `bool Something();`

Look at the other `Func<>` options to see which match what you're trying to accomplish. At the very least you're looking at either [`Action<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) or [`Func<bool, string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx)